# Почему не изменяются поля объектов?

Tags: python, ооп

Собственно код:

```py
class Warrior:
    hp = 100
    def attack(self, enemy):
        enemy.hp - 20

unit_1 = Warrior()
unit_2 = Warrior()

print(unit_1.hp, unit_2.hp)
unit_1.attack(unit_2)
unit_2.attack(unit_1)
print(unit_1.hp, unit_2.hp)
```

Выводит:

```
100 100

100 100
```

Хотя должно выводить по идее:

```
100 100

80 80
```

Почему так?

P.S. Я еще новичок, поэтому попрошу не кидаться помидорами

Comment: `enemy.hp - 20` на `enemy.hp -= 20`

Comment: @Alexander Спасибо)